# Using "would" + present simple in a conditional sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning, conditional-constructions

While watching a tv-series, I saw this sentence:

> A: I wonder what she will be wearing tonight. Do you
>   think she'll be in her high school field hockey uniform? That'd be
>   crazy, right?
>
> B: Yes, ***it'd be crazy if that's what she wears to a wedding***.

I wonder why this usage is fine. Is it fine because "character A" ask whether it ***would*** be crazy or not?

Is it okay to use "would" with past simple in a conditional sentence? I thought this would be better with second conditionals as:

> It would be crazy if she wore that to a wedding.

Comment: I find that use a little odd. But this is an area where many people are unsure, so I'm not surprised to see it used.

Comment: The real one or the one I suggested ?

Comment: The one you saw on TV.

Comment: The past simple there is actually *irrealis mood*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood

Comment: Both are quite normal expressions.